# Get documents from firebase by an array of documents IDs (Kotlin)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, document

is there any way to get documents from firebase by list of IDs?
I have this list:
`val IDs= listOf("id1","id2","id3","id4")`
and I want to get all those documents without looping through them.
something like this, if possible:
`Firebase.firestore.collection("users").documents(IDs).get()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Firestore client libraries don't have the notion of batch reads which would allow to retrieve a set of documents given it's ids. Nonetheless, you can still make queries that filter on the document id by using the `FieldPath.documentId()` [object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldPath). This value translates to a special sentinel that allows queries on the document id so you can write a query like below:

```
Firebase.firestore.collection("users")
                  .whereIn(FieldPath.documentId(), listOf("id1", "id2", [...], "id10"))
```

There's one restriction to note with this approach. The `whereIn` filter accepts at most [10 values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations). If you need to retrieve more it would be necessary to make several queries.

Alternatively, the approach suggested by Brettski of making a bunch of single document reads would work too.

Answer (score 2):

That isn't possible in Firestore. Id's can only be accessed directly through a collection/document request.

I don't know Kotlin, though in JavaScript I would perhaps approach it by creating an array of functions for each of the documents, then using a Promise.all() to retrieve them at once. It is, imo a downside of Firestore where you can't query for multiple Id's.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote as the base of the answer is that you can't query for multiple id's in firestore. Plus attempted to provide a previously used asynchronous approach to getting multiple id's.